# Android Animation - Rotate Image Moves Irregularly

Tags: android, animation

when start the animation it moves slow in the beginning and it gets faster as it move. anyone suggest me. here is my code

```
  Animation rotateAnim;
  rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
  rotateAnim.setDuration(60*1000);
  rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
  _mClockNeedle.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

Comment: Do u want to rotate it gradually from slow to fast in 1 min(as u have set duration 60*1000)?

Comment: i need like clock time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a [`AccelerateInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateInterpolator.html). The behavior you describe is how this class is made, as specified in the API. You may want to use the [`LinearInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator.html) instead, if you want it to move at a constant rate. There are also other subclasses of [`Interpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) to chose from.

If you wish for the animation to be shorter or longer this is done with the `setDuration` method, in milliseconds, as you've set it to 1 minute in your example.